# How to write *ngIf for input placeholder in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a template

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let text of texts[i]; let j = index">{{text}}
  <input type="text">
      </ng-container>
```

I also have an array `myWords`

```
myWords = ['orange', 'blue', 'green'];
```

How could I insert these words like a placeholder, but only in special case, like

```
this.app-part
```

I have 3 parts in my app, but I would like to have a placeholder (words from `myWords`)  only in 3rd part, and if I have 1st or 2nd part - I don't need any placeholder there.

Comment: You can bind placeholder like any other attribute, then just provide an empty string where you don't want one. But you can only have a single placeholder, it's not clear where the array of three values fits in.

Comment: What do you mean by a part here?

Comment: @Faisal I mean, I have 3 different parts, but they all have this component

Comment: And _what_ are the parts? What is an example of a part? Can you should an output of what you want to be rendered?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [the conditional operator `?:` in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to set the attribute `placeholder` either to a value or to an empty string. Setting the placeholder to an empty string should be the same as having it not set for most common use-cases.

To access the correct placeholder value, you'll need to assign `index` to a local template variable `j`.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let text of texts[i]; let j = index">
  {{ text }}
  <input type=text [placeholder]="condition ? myWords[j] : ''">
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a similar case with a boolean.

```html
<!-- if extraKilometers is true then I'll type 'Who?' else I'll type 'What?' -->
<textarea class="form-control input-wide-400" 
                              placeholder="{{extraKilometers ? 'Who?' : 'What?'}}" 
                              aria-label="distance" 
                              formControlName="description"
                              rows=2
                              id="transportDescription"></textarea>
```

In your specific example I'd use:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let text of texts; let j = index">{{text}}
  <input type="text" placeholder="{{ myWords[j] }}" >
</ng-container>
```

Here's a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ye37h) with the info you've given using this method

Comment: This one works. Its needs the double brackets surrounding the ternary

Answer (score 1):

for anybody looking for something similar(like I was) - you can also call method from placeholder like that:

`[placeholder]="someMethod() ? 'placeholder1' : 'placeholder2'"`

Comment: You should try and avoid method calls in your templates as the change detection will have to execute the method each time, you should have a boolean and it's state.